# Generating logic for possible output of all the combinations of string in a list

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to generate response as true or false if a code exists in the list. So I am able to generate the response if the string contains a 'single in-brackets' values for example:"ABC(Q,E,1)EEE", but if a string has multiple brackets like:"B(A,1)AA(E,Z)EE", I am not able to generate output from this. I am new to coding and building logics, it will be great if someone can help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the code you want to check: ");
        String input = scan.next();

        List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
        codes.add("ABC(Q,E,1)EEE");
        codes.add("ABDCE(E,Z,X)E");
        codes.add("B(A,1)AAEEE");
        codes.add("R(1,2,3,4,5)RT(U,M,N,B,V,H)(Q,E,R,F,G,H)(R,Z)");
        codes.add("B(A,1)AA(E,Z)EE");

        for (Iterator<String> i = codes.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            String code = i.next();

            String prefix = code.substring(0, code.indexOf("("));
            String suffix = code.substring(code.indexOf(")") + 1);
            String middle = code.substring(code.indexOf("(") + 1, code.indexOf(")"));
            String[] var = middle.split(",");

            String[] result = new String[var.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < var.length; j++) {

                result[j] = prefix + var[j] + suffix;

                if (result[j].equals(input)) {
                    System.out.println("True: This code is present");
                }
               }
              }
              }
```

Output (which works):

```
Enter the code you want to check: 
BAAAEEE                
True: The code is present
```

Output(not working):

```
Enter the code you want to check: 
BAAAZEE
<gives no output>
```

Let me give you an example(for "ABC(Q,E,1)EEE") of what is being done: it makes three possible outputs of this string that are: "ABCQEEE", "ABCEEEE", "ABC1EEE". So if i give the input as "ABCQEEE" , it will generate these outputs internally and give me output as True if the code is present anywhere in the list.

Comment: `You will understand what I am trying to do here by looking over the code` ... this is not an acceptable question.  It is _your_ job to invest at least some time to help us to understand the problem(s) in your code.

Comment: Your ```main``` method is incomplete. Kindly edit it. And include what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen apologize for it, I have edited the question

Comment: Clarify your question more by adding sample input and sample output.

Comment: Sorry, but we still cant' help. You should first **clearly** state your requirement: what is the exact nature of the strings coming in, and what is the exact nature of the check you intend to do?! *We* need that information to help you, but much more importantly: that is what **you** need to solve this problem. Right now, it looks like you are solving a complex computer science problem (about which "words" are legit within a "language") with insufficient ideas. In other words: the first step to solve such a task is to **understand** exactly what it is about!

Comment: Add an example of input that works and one that doesn't work and you have still not clarified what the issue is with your homework.

Comment: And for the record: this is not only about *single* examples. The real task here is to understand "what properties distinguishes *valid* input from *invalid* one". Just giving one, two examples doesn't necessarily give enough details to make that decision!

Comment: @GhostCat please see if I made my question clear.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson added example to clarify the question

Comment: Err, you are re-inventing regular expressions. Like `ABC[Q,E,1]EEE` would nicely match any value that starts ABC ... has one of Q E 1 ... followed by 3 Es. So: research regular expressions. As said, this is a fundamental thing in computer science. And hint: if your task is to create your own regular expression engine, then talk to your teacher and ask him for more guidance. As your current attempts are (sorry, but true) hopelessly insufficient to get there.

Comment: Can you use a third party library or do you have to code it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have to do is to out put true or false depending on the user input, you can convert your code strings to regular expressions and check if input matches the list of regex.

Steps:

- Convert each element in your codes list to a regex

  // convert "ABC(Q,E,1)EEE" to "ABC[QE1]EEE" to match each string starting with ABC followed by one of [QE1] and ending with EEE

  //"R(1,2,3,4,5)RT(U,M,N,B,V,H)(Q,E,R,F,G,H)(R,Z)" to "R[12345]RT[UMNBVH][QERFGH][RZ]"

  etc
- Check if input matches one of the regexes

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the code you want to check: ");
    String input = scan.next();

    List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
    codes.add("ABC(Q,E,1)EEE");
    codes.add("ABDCE(E,Z,X)E");
    codes.add("B(A,1)AAEEE");
    codes.add("R(1,2,3,4,5)RT(U,M,N,B,V,H)(Q,E,R,F,G,H)(R,Z)");
    codes.add("B(A,1)AA(E,Z)EE");

    //list to store the modified strings
    List<String> modifiedCodes = new ArrayList<>();
    //for each string in list find if there is a pattern like '('some chars')'
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)");
    for (Iterator<String> i = codes.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String code = i.next();
        StringBuffer  sb = new StringBuffer ();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
         while (m.find()) { 
            String match = m.group();
            //if found a match replace '(' and ')' with '[' and ']' and remove commas
            m.appendReplacement(sb, match.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']').replace(",", ""));
          }
          m.appendTail(sb);
          //add modified string to list
          modifiedCodes.add(sb.toString());
    }     

    boolean codeIsPresent = false;
    for(String code: modifiedCodes){
        //check if input matches one of the regex in the list 'modifiedCodes'
        if (input.matches(code)) {
            codeIsPresent = true;
            System.out.println("True: This code is present");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!codeIsPresent){
        System.out.println("Code not found");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

> how can we print the list of all the combinations of the string from
>   which it is getting the output? say, I just have a string
>   "BA(1,2,3)QW(A-Z,0-9)" and I want all the possible combinations of it

The above question from your coments is slightly difference as the original post, it might be better if you post a new question. You can create your own algorithm with somekind of tree structure to solve the issue but it can be very hackish and messy. I would suggest to use a 3rd party libraray like [generex](https://github.com/mifmif/Generex) if possible. You can download the jar [from the maven repo here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mifmif/generex/1.0.1). With generex you can have all your possible commbinations:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    //change your input to a regular expression
    //"BA(1,2,3)QW(A-Z,0-9)"  to  "BA[1-3]QW[A-Z][0-9]"
    Generex generex = new Generex("BA[1-3]QW[A-Z][0-9]");
    List<String> matchedStrs = generex.getAllMatchedStrings();
    matchedStrs.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: and if there is a code "B(A,1)AAEE(All)" and I need to treat this 'all' as if it contains all alphabets(A-Z) and numbers(0-9). How can this be treated?

Comment: You can add "B[A1]AAEE[A-Z0-9]". The character class [A-Z0-9] means any char from A to Z or any digit from 0 to 9

Comment: got it, had a little confusion but you cleared it

Comment: This actually is a better answer. @kitrak You should change the accepted answer to this. :)

Comment: @Eritrean how can we print the list of all the combinations of the string from which it is getting the output? say, I just have a string "BA(1,2,3)QW(A-Z,0-9)" and I want all the possible combinations of it.

Comment: @kitrak please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: thank you so much @Eritrean I will try this by making a maven project

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
**Edited** : Added code comments.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the code you want to check: ");
        String input = scan.next();
        scan.close();

        List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
        codes.add("ABC(Q,E,1)EEE");
        codes.add("ABDCE(E,Z,X)E");
        codes.add("B(A,1)AAEEE");
        codes.add("R(1,2,3,4,5)RT(U,M,N,B,V,H)(Q,E,R,F,G,H)(R,Z)");
        codes.add("B(A,1)AA(E,Z)EE");

        for (Iterator<String> i = codes.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String code = i.next();
            List<String> codePossiblity = generatePossibilities(code);
            // check if the input is in the list of all the possibility
            for (String s : codePossiblity) {
                if (s.contains(input)) {
                    System.out.println("True: This code is present");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /* This method removes the parenthesis and generates all the possibilities.
     * This method assumes that the parenthesis always comes in pair, thus
     * for every opening parenthesis ["("] there is a closing parenthesis [")"]
     * Example if the "code" is [A(WX)C(YZ)] then it will generate AWCY, AWCZ, AXCY and AXCZ 
     * 
     * @param code - The string which contains parenthesis.
     * @return a list of all the possibilities
     */
    public static List<String> generatePossibilities(String code) {
        // This will hold the left part of the possibleCodes (part before "(")
        List<String> possibleCodeList = new LinkedList<>();
        String s = code;
        boolean first = true;

        // Loop while an open parenthesis ["("] can be found
        while (s.contains("(")) {
            // Retrieve from the string the first substring where "(" starts and ends with ")"
            // In the example, in the first iteration will be "WX"
            // in the second iteration this will be "YZ"
            String inside = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1, s.indexOf(")"));

            // Retrieve the list inside the "(" and ")"
            // In the example, in the first iteration the list will have "W", "X"
            // in the second iteration the list will have "Y", "Z"
            String[] listOfChoices = inside.split(",");

            // This will hold the right part of the possibleCodes (part after ")")
            List<String> listOfCombinations = new LinkedList<>();

            // Loop all the possible choices
            for (String choice : listOfChoices) {
                // If it is the first iteration then you need to include those characters before the "("
                if (first) {
                    // add the characters before the "(" and the remaining characters after ")"
                    // In the example, the first iteration of this list ("W", "X") will add "AWC(YZ)"
                    // the second iteration of this list ("W", "X") will add "AXC(YZ)"
                    listOfCombinations.add(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("(")) + choice + s.substring(s.indexOf(")") + 1));
                } 
                // Else just start with choice
                else {
                    // add the remaining characters after ")"
                    // In the example, the first iteration of this list ("Y", "Z") will add "Y"
                    // the second iteration of this list ("Y", "Z") will add "Z"
                    listOfCombinations.add(choice + s.substring(s.indexOf(")") + 1));
                }
            }
            // Remove the subtring before the ")", in the example this will be "C(YZ)"
            s = s.substring(s.indexOf(")") + 1);

            // If it is the first iteration then you just need to assign the listOfCombinations directly to possibleCodeList, 
            // since possibleCodeList is still empty
            if (first) {
                possibleCodeList = listOfCombinations;
                first = false;
            } 
            // Else combine the left and right part
            else {
                List<String> codePossiblity2 = new LinkedList<>();
                // Iterate though all the list of possible codes since we want all the elements in the list to be concatenated with the right half of the string
                // The list will have "AWC(YZ)" and "AXC(YZ)"
                for (String possibleCodes : possibleCodeList) {
                    // Iterate the possible combinations of the right half of the original string (the second pair of "()")
                    // The list will have "Y" and "Z"
                    for (String sTmp : listOfCombinations) {
                        // Replace the string which are inside the "()" in the left half of the original string.
                        // Replace it with the right half of the original string
                        // In the string of "AWC(YZ)" replace "(YZ)" with "Y"
                        // In the string of "AWC(YZ)" replace "(YZ)" with "Z"
                        // In the string of "AXC(YZ)" replace "(YZ)" with "Y"
                        // In the string of "AXC(YZ)" replace "(YZ)" with "Z"
                        String t = possibleCodes.replace("(" + inside + ")", sTmp);
                        // add the newly created string to codePossiblity2
                        codePossiblity2.add(t);
                    }

                    // At the end of the loop above codePossiblity2 will have these values
                    // AWCY, AWCZ, AXCY and AXCZ
                }

                // overwrite the possibleCodeList since we have now a new left part of the string
                possibleCodeList = codePossiblity2;
            }
        }

        return possibleCodeList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what your code does and how it helps solving the issue.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have added the comments. Sorry about that since I was quite busy. :)